# How to run PySpark jobs from a local Jupyter notebook to a Spark master in a Docker container?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Docker container that's running Apache Spark with a master and a slave worker. I'm attempting to submit a job from a Jupyter notebook on the host machine. See below:

```
# Init
!pip install findspark
import findspark
findspark.init()


# Context setup
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
# Docker container is exposing port 7077
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('test').setMaster('spark://localhost:7077')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc

# Execute step
import random
num_samples = 1000
def inside(p):     
  x, y = random.random(), random.random()
  return x*x + y*y < 1
count = sc.parallelize(range(0, num_samples)).filter(inside).count()
pi = 4 * count / num_samples
print(pi)
```

The execute step shows the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
    Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 172.17.0.2, executor 0): 

    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/omar/anaconda3/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory
```

It looks to me that the command is trying to run Spark job locally when it should be send it to the Spark master specified in the previous steps. Is this not possible through a Jupyter notebook?

My container is based off of https://hub.docker.com/r/p7hb/docker-spark/ but I installed Python 3.6 under `/usr/bin/python3.6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do the following **before I created the SparkContext**:

```
import os
# Path on master/worker where Python is installed
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = '/usr/bin/python3.6'
```

Some research showed that I need to add this to `/usr/local/spark/conf/spark-env.sh` via:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON='/usr/bin/python3.6'
```

But that isn't working.

Comment: A cursory look through the source code reveals that PySpark reads the location of the Python interpreter from the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variable of the driver script and then broadcasts it to all executors together with each work item. When you use `spark-submit`, this variable is set to what the Spark master has in its environment, configurable via `spark-env.sh`. When you use `findspark` instead, e.g., in a notebook, it uses the environment of the current interpreter, which is why you need to assign to `os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON']`.

Comment: For those who like poking around source code, it's right [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e24f0dcd2754a1db27e9b0f3cf27ee6d7229f717/python/pyspark/context.py#L209) in the initalisation function of PySpark's `SparkContext` class. The value of `SparkContext.pythonExec` is attached to each work item sent to the executors and is used by them to launch Python - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60832794/1374437).