# Change PYSPARK_PYTHON on Spark workers

Tags: python, apache-spark, ubuntu, pyspark, environment-variables

We distribute our Python app, which uses Spark, together with Python 3.7 interpreter (`python.exe` with all necessary libs lies near `MyApp.exe`).

To set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` we have have function which determines the path to our `python.exe`:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = get_python()
```

on Windows `PYSPARK_PYTHON` will become `C:/MyApp/python.exe`
on Ubuntu `PYSPARK_PYTHON` will become `/opt/MyApp/python.exe`

We start the master/driver node and create `SparkSession` on Windows. Then we start the worker node on Ubuntu but the worker fails with:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 1614, 10.0.2.15, executor 1): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:/MyApp/python.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Of course, there is no `C:/MyApp/python.exe` on ubuntu.

If I understand this error correctly, `PYSPARK_PYTHON` from driver is sent to all workers.

Also tried to set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` in `spark-env.sh` and `spark-defaults.conf`. How can I change `PYSPARK_PYTHON` on Ubuntu workers to become `/opt/MyApp/python.exe`?

Comment: Is there only one Windows machine? Does the Spark master on the Windows machine also host executors? If the answers are yes and no respectively, they you can try running the master on an Ubuntu node too.

Comment: On Windows machine I start master and worker.
On Ubuntu only worker.

Answer (score -1):

Browsing through the souce code, it looks like the Python driver code puts the value of the Python executable path from its Spark context when creating work items for running Python functions in [`spark/rdd.py`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1fd4607d844905f10fe1edbfd6282c25b95b233d/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L2500):

```
def _wrap_function(sc, func, deserializer, serializer, profiler=None):
    assert deserializer, "deserializer should not be empty"
    assert serializer, "serializer should not be empty"
    command = (func, profiler, deserializer, serializer)
    pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
    return sc._jvm.PythonFunction(bytearray(pickled_command), env, includes, sc.pythonExec,
                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                  sc.pythonVer, broadcast_vars, sc._javaAccumulator)
```

The Python runner [`PythonRunner.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6fd3138e9c3c1d703f2a66bcdf17555803547774/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/python/PythonRunner.scala#L94) then uses the path stored in the first work item it receives to launch new interpreter instances:

```
private[spark] abstract class BasePythonRunner[IN, OUT](
    funcs: Seq[ChainedPythonFunctions],
    evalType: Int,
    argOffsets: Array[Array[Int]])
  extends Logging {
  ...
  protected val pythonExec: String = funcs.head.funcs.head.pythonExec
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ...
  def compute(
      inputIterator: Iterator[IN],
      partitionIndex: Int,
      context: TaskContext): Iterator[OUT] = {
    ...
    val worker: Socket = env.createPythonWorker(pythonExec, envVars.asScala.toMap)
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Based on that, I'm afraid that it seems not currently possible to have separate configurations for the Python executable in the master and in the workers. Also see the third comment to issue [SPARK-26404](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26404). Perhaps you should file an RFE with the Apache Spark project.

I'm not a Spark guru though and there might still be a way to do it, perhaps by setting `PYSPARK_PYTHON` to just `"python"` and then making sure the system `PATH` is configured accordingly so that your Python executable comes first.

Comment: Probably because it is outright incorrect? Spark [provides tools](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables) for separating driver and executor Python exec and there are literally [hundreds of questions referencing these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON+).